# plotting a matrix by row, colored and dashed by other column values R

Tags: r, matrix, plot, ggplot2

I have a matrix with 7 columns, and approximately 30 rows. The first two columns are categorical variables of strings, with the first having place names (ex: San Francisco) and the second having a Y/N value. Each of the other columns corresponds to a year (2006, 2008, etc.) and contains values that correspond to the year (col) and the place (row).

I need to make a plot that has one line per row, that are colored according to the place name (if there are two rows that both belong to San Francisco, they should be the same color), and dashed or solid according to the Y/N value.

I am working in R - Should I use ggplot, matplot, plot, or another plot package? I can almost get it to work in matplot, but the subtleties of getting the color and dashing to work seems impossible.

here's more or less what the data looks like (there are often NaN values):

colnames - location, YorN, 2006, 2008, 2009, 2011, 2012

row1 - "San Francisco", "Y", 0.1, 5.2, 3.5, 6, NaN

row2 - "San Francisco", "N", 3, 7.1, 2.2, NaN, 1

row3 - "New York", "Y", 4.2, 4.5, NaN, 1.1, 2

row4 - "New York", "N", 2, NaN, 2.1, 4.9, 6.7

Comment: If you gave us a small sample of example data, this would be super easy to answer. As it stands, it's almost impossible to answer.

Comment: `ggplot2` would make this easy. melt your data (using `reshape2`) and then use (something like) `ggplot(melted,aes(x=Year,y=value))+geom_line(colour=placename,linetype=yesno)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 dd <- read.csv(text='
       location, YorN, 2006, 2008, 2009, 2011, 2012
       "San Francisco", "Y", 0.1, 5.2, 3.5, 6, NaN
       "San Francisco", "N", 3, 7.1, 2.2, NaN, 1
        "New York", "Y", 4.2, 4.5, NaN, 1.1, 2
        "New York", "N", 2, NaN, 2.1, 4.9, 6.7')

 library("ggplot2"); theme_set(theme_bw())
 library("reshape2")
 ddm <- melt(dd)  ## uses factor columns as ID variables
 ## convert year back to numeric (alternatively, use check.names=FALSE
 ## in read.csv())
 ddm <- transform(ddm,year=as.numeric(gsub("^X","",variable)))
 ggplot(ddm,aes(x=year,y=value))+
      geom_line(aes(colour=location,linetype=YorN))
```

Comment: When I do this, the transform() step just adds a column of NA to my ddm matrix. Should I modify the parameters in gsub() somehow?

Comment: I don't know.  Would need to see a *reproducible* example (i.e., I can't guess wrong with your data frame without seeing it, or at least the results of `summary()` or `str()`